# mysql merge two queries on same table

Tags: mysql

Relevant DB info: I have two tables `students` and `links`, they are related via a foreign key in the links table `links.student_id` and therefore one student can have many links. The links table has a column named `status`.

Using a query I would like to:

1. Select students that have no entries in the related links table
2. Select students that have related links, but the most recent link should not have a status of active

I managed to write the queries for each of the above points:

```
// 1. students with no links
select s.id
from students s
left join links l
    on l.student_id = s.id
where l.student_id is null
```

and

```
// 2. students where last link is not complete
select l2.student_id as id
from links l1
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) as link_id, student_id, status
    FROM links
    where status != 'active'
    GROUP BY student_id
) l2 on l1.id = l2.link_id
```

But ideally this would be written in one query and I'm unsure what is the correct way to do this. I tried using a union like this:

```
select students.name
from students
join (
    select s.id as id
    from students s
    left join links l
        on l.student_id = s.id
    where l.student_id is null
    UNION ALL
    select l2.student_id as id
    from links l1
    JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(id) as link_id, student_id, status
        FROM links
        where status != 'active'
        GROUP BY student_id
    ) l2 on l1.id = l2.link_id
) as s1 on s1.id = students.id
```

But it doesn't seem to yield the correct results.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I don't think your second query does what you think it should do.

Comment: I think you're right

Comment: Should I be using having instead of where

Comment: *Select students that have related links, but the most recent link should not have a status of active*: you want the student filtered out, or just the most recent link?

Comment: Students filtered out - meaning I only care about getting the student info. I should only see students if their most recent link does not have a status of active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should do it:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM students a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT student_id, max(id) AS id
    FROM links
    GROUP BY student_id
) b on a.id = b.student_id
LEFT JOIN links c ON c.id = b.id
WHERE c.status IS NULL 
      OR c.status != 'active'
GROUP BY a.id
```

It works like this:

1. Grab all students (a)
2. Join with a temporary table (b) made of the most recent links per each student
3. Join back with the main links table based on the IDs of the most recent links
4. Keep only the records that don't have a link or those for which the status of the link is not 'active'

Comment: Tried it out and it seems to work great. That took me a good minute to understand 3 though, I think that was the missing piece! Thanks for your answer and for clearly explaining it.